# iscroll scrollToElement not updating currPage variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll4

*UPDATE:
I was able to get my scroller working as desired but I feel like I have hacked around the actual issue and would love it if anyone has a more solid answer, I've updated and noted in the snippets below the new jQuery I'm using.*

I'm using iScroll-4 (http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) for an iPad/Android web app, everything's working perfectly with the swipes and scrolling but I have a table of contents at the beginning of the app that allows users to jump to specific areas of the scroller --

I'm using the iScroll function `scrollToElement(element, duration)` in order to jump to the different areas. Also using `scrollToPage(page, duration)` to allow the user to manually navigate forward and backward one page at a time.

While watching the console logs the `currPageX` variable updates when I navigate with the `scrollToPage` function and when I swipe, but when using the `scrollToElement` the `currPageX` variable does not update.

Therefore if I jump to an element and then navigate forward with `scrollToPage('next', 0)` it will go backwards and navigate me to the next page after the table of contents.

I have tried using the `scroll.refresh()` function after `scrollToElement`, before, putting the function inside a timeout, etc. and I can't figure out why the `currPageX` is not updating.

Here's a snippet of the jQuery code that I'm using the two different functions:

```
  // TO NAVIGATE FORWARD AND BACKWARDS
  $('span.control').on('click', function() {
    var slideDir = $(this).attr('data-dir');
    if (slideDir == 'prev') {
      var tehPg = tehScroll.currPageX-1;
    } else if (slideDir == 'next') {
      var tehPg = tehScroll.currPageX+1;
    }
    tehScroll.scrollToPage(tehPg, 0);
    return false;
  });

  // TO JUMP FROM CONTENTS
  $('li[data-page="toc"] span').on('click', function() {
    var toPage = $(this).attr('data-page');
    tehScroll.scrollToElement('li[data-page="'+toPage+'"]', 800);
    // ADDED THE FOLLOWING LINE TO MANUALLY SET currPageX after scrolling!
    tehScroll.currPageX = $('#slides li[data-page="'+toPage+'"]').index();
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: I am using version 5 of iScroll and had the same problem. The way I solved it was by writing  
**`tehScroll.currentPage.pageY`**  
instead of  
**`tehScroll.currPageX`**  
Also, what's the purpose of that **`return false`** at the bottom?

Comment: `return false` will stop the default action of the clicked element, so for an `a` tag that would be navigating to the `href`, however, in this case, because the click handler is on a `span`, it does precisely nothing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using [jquery-mobile-iscrollview](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview) widget plug-in? - there is a function scrollToPage(pageX, pageY, time), works well for me...

best

M